# can we use JQuery validations in partial view user control in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have controls like Textbox, dropdown on my CustomerDetails.ascx partialview.

Now can we do JQuery validations on the user controls.

In the MainView, we use code like this.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Mvc.Master" 
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<DataModel.CustomerMaster>>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphHead" runat="server">

    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //JQuery validations
    </script>        
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent" runat="server">
    <h2 class="pageName">Customer Profile Main View</h2>
</asp:Content>
```

In the PartialView, we use code like this.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<DataModel.CustomerMaster>" %>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="Form_Label">
                <label for="Zip">Zip</label><em>*</em>
            </td>
            <td CssClass="Form_Value">
                <%= Html.TextBox("AddressDetail.ZipCode", Model.AddressDetail.FirstOrDefault().ZipCode, new { @class = "required zip", minlength = "5"})%>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" align="center">
                <input type="submit" value="Update" /> 
                <span id="spanUpdateProfile" style="background-color:White;color:Green;font-size:small"></span>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

JQuery validation purely work on the client side (html level), so it doesn't matter whether it's on the partial view or full view.

Answer (score 1):

When you think of partial views in mvc, they're probably closer to PHP's include() than to webforms custom controls.  So just think of it as plugging in html or javascript/jquery somewhere in the middle of the page :-)